# Changing the color of specific text and also selecting it (visual basics word) Pin

Tags: vba, ms-word

Helo, acording to this code (In Visual Basic for word):
The code works for me, but it is not what I want...

The problem is: I only wont to select a colored text (example -> A text colored in Red), selecting all the words colored by Red.
I am very frustrated because I have tried everything but it does not work for me.
My goal is to **select** only the blue colored text or the red colored text in my principle document, for example.
The colors i have in the document are siple; red, blue, green, white, whele, and the most important text its colored in Sky Blue.
Sorry for the writing and thank you for your trouble.

//Replace text color//

```
Sub ChangeColorWithReplace()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = -603914241
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: *"My goal is taking that colored text to another word document."* - what does that mean? Do you want to copy the text from one document to another, or do you want to cut the text and paste into a new document? When you put the text into the new document does it simply get dumped all in one paragraph, or put in separate paragraphs, or does the text need to be placed in a specific location? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64751762/edit) your question with the answers.

Comment: You also need to confirm that the text you want to find is Red, i.e. it has an RGB value of 255,0,0. If it is formatted with a theme color a different property is required to find it. Again, please edit your question with these additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
Sub CopyRedContent()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument: Set DocTgt = Documents.Add
With DocSrc.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    DocTgt.Range.Characters.Last.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    DocTgt.Range.InsertAfter vbCr
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
        .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then
          .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
    End If
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Set DocSrc = Nothing: Set DocTgt = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you i am totally grateful, 
i thought it would be easier to 
but no i can see the complexity of the matter... 
It helps me a lot for what I want to do with it. :) :) :)

Comment: ITS WORKING 100% THIS GUY ITS AMAZING. THANK YOU.